# JS code not working

Tags: javascript, html

i need your help. I am a beginner in the programming area, i'm still doing a couple of basics courses.. Anyway, i'm trying to make a code work, but i'm not being able to.. hope some of you can help me. I'll post the code and explain what I'd like to do.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<title>My Quiz</title>
</head> 
  <body>
   <input type="button" value="OK" onclick="funcao();">
   <textarea id="output"></textarea>
   <br>
   <script>
     function funcao(){
        document.getElementById("output").value;
       alert("Let me guess, you wrote that: " + output);
      }
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, i'd like to take what the user typed and then show it on the screen. I made a function called `(funcao)` for that. But instead of showing me what the user typed it appears a message: `[HTMLTextAreaElement]`

I'll be glad if anyone can point me what i'm doing wrong.
Big thx! Cheers from Brazil!

Answer (score 2):

You need to store `output` to a variable

```
function funcao(){
    var output = document.getElementById("output").value; // declare output variable here
    alert("Let me guess, you wrote that: " + output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget to assign textarea value to `output` variable:

```
function funcao(){
    var output = document.getElementById("output").value;
    alert("Let me guess, you wrote that: " + output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the value to `output`.

```
function funcao(){
    var output=document.getElementById("output").value;
    alert("Let me guess, you wrote that: " + output);
}
```